# MySQL displaying incorrect data

Tags: mysql

Besides the question above I'd like to know if there is any way to optimize this MySQL statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE
  `category` = 3073 OR
  `category` = 3074 OR
  `category` = 3100 OR
  `category` = 3102 OR
  `category` = 3106 OR
  `category` = 3109 OR
  `category` = 3111 OR
  `category` = 3115 OR
  `category` = 3130 OR
  `category` = 3134 OR
  `category` = 3144 OR
  `category` = 3146 OR
  `category` = 3152 OR
  `category` = 3157 OR
  `category` = 3162 OR
  `category` = 3163 OR
  `category` = 3164 OR
  `category` = 3166 OR
  `category` = 3167 OR
  `category` = 3168 OR
  `category` = 3170 OR
  `category` = 3171 OR
  `category` = 3177 OR
  `category` = 3181 OR
  `category` = 3182 OR
  `category` = 3184 OR
  `category` = 3190 OR
  `category` = 3191 OR
  `category` = 3192 OR
  `category` = 3213 OR
  `category` = 3224 OR
  `category` = 3227 OR
  `category` = 3228 OR
  `category` = 3235 OR
  `category` = 3238 OR
  `category` = 3239 OR
  `category` = 3240 OR
  `category` = 3244 OR
  `category` = 3245 OR
  `category` = 3246 AND
  `active` = 1 AND
  `price_notax` > 0 AND
  `deleted` = 0
ORDER BY `position` ASC
LIMIT 0, 24;
```

This statement is also displaying the products which have field value of `price_notax` equal to `0`, why? I stated the number need to be higher than `0`...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should group your ORs and ANDs.  Also, to make things more readable, use the IN() statement instead of all of those ORs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When that WHERE clause is evaluated, any of the ORed clauses being true will make the state of the AND clauses irrelevant. To correct this you must surround the set of OR clauses with parentheses so they are evaluated separately...

But to accomplish the same thing with greater readability, use an IN clause, instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE category IN (3073, 3074, 3100, 3102, 3106, 3109, 3111, 3115, 3130, 3134, 3144, 3146, 3152, 3157, 3162, 3163, 3164, 3166, 3167, 3168, 3170, 3171, 3177, 3181, 3182, 3184, 3190, 3191, 3192, 3213, 3224, 3227, 3228, 3235, 3238, 3239, 3240, 3244, 3245, 3246) 
AND active = 1 
AND price_notax > 0 
AND deleted = 0 
ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 0, 24;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE category in (3073, 3074) -- and so on
AND `active` = 1
AND `price_notax` > 0 
AND `deleted` = 0 
ORDER BY `position` -- ASC is by default
LIMIT 0, 24
```

Your query display wrong result because you use OR AND, so if just one of condition is true (for example, category=3100) then it display it.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because "and" has precedence over "or" and in your statement only the last part will be "anded" to `category` = 3246. You need to put brackets () around the or part.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create an array of those category IDs and then use

```
    WHERE category IN somearray
```

Answer (score 0):

`OR` has lesser priority than `AND`.

More correct SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE ( 
    `category` = 3073 OR `category` = 3074 OR `category` = 3100 OR 
    `category` = 3102 OR `category` = 3106 OR `category` = 3109 OR 
    `category` = 3111 OR `category` = 3115 OR `category` = 3130 OR 
    `category` = 3134 OR `category` = 3144 OR `category` = 3146 OR 
    `category` = 3152 OR `category` = 3157 OR `category` = 3162 OR 
    `category` = 3163 OR `category` = 3164 OR `category` = 3166 OR 
    `category` = 3167 OR `category` = 3168 OR `category` = 3170 OR 
    `category` = 3171 OR `category` = 3177 OR `category` = 3181 OR 
    `category` = 3182 OR `category` = 3184 OR `category` = 3190 OR 
    `category` = 3191 OR `category` = 3192 OR `category` = 3213 OR 
    `category` = 3224 OR `category` = 3227 OR `category` = 3228 OR 
    `category` = 3235 OR `category` = 3238 OR `category` = 3239 OR 
    `category` = 3240 OR `category` = 3244 OR `category` = 3245 OR 
    `category` = 3246 )
    AND `active` = 1 
    AND `price_notax` > 0 
    AND `deleted` = 0 
ORDER BY `position` ASC 
LIMIT 0, 24;
```